# Python 'global' return "name is not defined"

Tags: python, python-2.7

With the code below

```
def A():    
    print "in A"

    def B():
        global x
        x += 1
        y += 1
        print "in B"

    x = 0
    y = 0
    print x, y                    
    B()
    print x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    A()
```

I got the below output and error

```
in A
0 0
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

What is the right way of using global? Actually, I'm trying to change x in subfunction B and return it to A. Also try to check out non-global y, and see what happen in outer function.

---

Got it from hint given by Haidro

```
def A():

    print "in A"

    def B():
        global x        
        x += 1
        y = 1
        print "in B"

    global x
    x = 0
    y = 0
    print x, y                    
    B()
    print x, y
```

Comment: It's not totally clear where you're going with this, but IMO `global` should be avoided.

Comment: what's the best way to replace global? pass in as parameter?

Comment: @twfx use a class. Check my answer :) (the bottom of it)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to put `global x` in `A()` as well:

```
def A():    
    print "in A"

    def B():
        global x
        global y # Also, don't forget to globalise y!
        x += 1
        y += 1
        print "in B"
    global x
    global y
    x = 0
    y = 0
    print x, y                    
    B()
    print x, y


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    A()
```

You have to put `global x` in `A()` so it can be accessed in `B()`. However, you still have to leave `global x` in `B()` so you don't get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

---

You might want to re-think your structure. Perhaps use a class?

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def A(self):
        print "in A"
        print self.x, self.y      
        self.B()
        print self.x, self.y

    def B(self):
        self.x += 1
        self.y += 1
        print "in B"

me = MyClass() # Create an instance of the class
me.A()
me.B()
print me.x, me.y
```

This returns:

```
in A
0 0
in B
1 1
in B
2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you don't really want to use globals. In general they should only be used when absolutely necessary. I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
def A():    
    print "in A"
    x = 5
    def B(x):
        print "in B"
        return x

    print B(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    A()
```